# Cannot install windows 7 or ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, laptop, installation

I'm having a strange issue. My laptop was running on windows 7 previously and sometimes it was restarting and getting stucked. So I tried to reinstall windows 7.
When I try to install windows it goes with the first phase (loading from the CD and copying files). And then always get stuccked in the starting windows phase. It stops when the windows logo arrives (I can only see start of the windows logo animation).
Then I tried to install Ubuntu, but no success. It again stucked in the middle.

But for some reason I can install windows XP.  After that I have installed all the drivers and all the devices are working correct.

I'm not sure what is happening please help me ...
Laptop version : Acer Aspire 4738z
Ubuntu version : 12.10

Comment: What model of laptop? What version of Ubuntu were you trying?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart , I have added the versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem before, multiple times actually and have different solutions to them all. Some requires a hardware fix, some requires an ISO fix.

1. You might want to check your copy of Windows, that you burn onto a CD. It might be a faulty ISO, or   you might have burn it at a faster speed (say 32x) causing some bad writes onto the CD.

1.1 Your DVD Burner might be faulty. (Hardware Issue)

2. Check if your Hard disk drive is still spinning during the installation. If it stops spinning, there's a chance that the installation is actually stuck, this maybe due to problem (1) as above.

2.1 It might also be a good idea to check if your Hard disk drive is faulty.

3. Doing a memtest86 to see if you have a faulty ram. If you have one, that might be the problem. From my experienced, I took out one ram from my laptop and tried to re-install Windows, everything worked out great. All I have to do is get a new pair or stick of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have tried several CDS as well as booting from the USB which I came across the same issue. I'll try your last suggestion. Removing one of the RAM.

Comment: " I took out one ram from my laptop and tried to re-install Windows, everything worked out great" ah this solved my issue as well. How ever   I have 2 stiks of RAM 2GB (came with laptop) and GB new. It sucks at the same point when windows 7 is loading when only 4GB is connected. But 2GB only works.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons :

- Your CPU is getting over heated and the processor stops abruptly leaving your screen frozen.
- The power supply (Battery ->equivalent of a PSU) is not delivering enough amps consistently to your HD
- RAM is faulty

Solutions:

- Download a diagnosis/monitoring software like Everest and memtest and see if any of the components give bad values.

Comment: Thanks for the info. CPU is not overheated (I don't feel it ). But it can be a power supply issue since it was restarting when power supply is plugged previously. That's why I formated and tried to install OS.  But after installing windows XP , it is not restarting when the cable connected.

Comment: Could be that Win XP is not maxing out any of your components like - Processor/Opticcal drive etc.  But Win 8 and Ubunutu might be maxing it.  If you try to max your resource using some software in XP, does your system freeze / shut down?  If it does, PSU is probably the cause.  If not, we will have to diagnose more.

Comment: I get the notification from the battery that it is 100% charged. Is this means that power supply is working correct   ?

Comment: I mean not that supply.  I mean the PSU inside your laptop.  The one that gives the 5v lines to various components.  Like the PSU in PC.

Comment: My mistake, laptops dont have PSUs like traditional PCs.  Sorry.  So, I think the issue might be the current being delivered by the Battery.  May be it is not consistent.  If your laptop can work without a battery, by only connecting the supply (my Dell works), try installing Win8 that way only with direct power, no battery.  If it does not hang, we can identify battery output current as the issue.

Comment: I have tryied using only the direct power, but still nothing changed.

Comment: I have installed Everest . Battery voltage is 12.2.. V most of the time when the cable is plugged. http://www.ibuybattery.com/acer-aspire-4738z-battery.htm this says it is around 10.8 V is that can be a problem?

Comment: @Jayantha Sorry, I am not able to diagnose from my end.  I dont know.  Battery is not an issues I guess.  12.2 V seems ok.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Removing newly installed RAM worked.